# IntelliJ vs Gradle JDK versions

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Can someone explain the difference between the Java version specified in Gradle's `java` block vs in the IntelliJ IDEA Project Structure dialog?

[image: IntelliJ Screen Capture]

I know the JVM that's used to execute Gradle itself is specified in Settings, so neither is that. I assume the program in question is being built for `targetCompatibility` in Gradle, but if that is the case what does the Project Structure dialog define?

Comment: Let me know if you can find a complete and consistent answer to this. It's confused me for over a decade now.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, the Gradle targetCompatibility settings are the same thing as the Project Structure's settings.

Let's take a look at the javac command output:

```
  --release <release>
        Compile for the specified Java SE release. Supported releases: 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20
  
  --source <release>, -source <release>
        Provide source compatibility with the specified Java SE release. Supported releases: 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20
```

Every JDK version has a release number, and usually, the higher version of JDK(take 20 for example), can compile and run all lower-release versions.

However, if you are using JDK 8, you can only compile Java 8 sources level and can't compile Java source level 9, 10, etc, and also can only run Java 8 class.

Every class file has an internal version number, which shows the least JVM version it can be run at, this is specified by the javac --release arg value.

So back to Gradle, the screenshot suggests that the project at least uses JDK 8 to compile and run it, so the IDEA will pick a real JDK 17 to compile and run it. Sure the JDK 17 can compile and run more recent Java source code levels including Java 8.

I've drawn a small image for that concept:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `Project Structure` dialog defines the version of Java that is being used for purposes of Intellij IDEA, e.g. for code completion or to show you compilation errors in real time. In short, it is used for coding. For example, if you choose `<NO SDK>` in the `Project Structure` you will still be able to run Gradle but you won't be able to write a code. And to give you the opportunity to write a code on the version of Java that you want, you can choose the language level in the `Project Structure`, but it will still be used for coding, not for compilation using Gradle.